# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.<SpringBoot>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm starting with SpringBoot and I have to do a HelloWold but enable SSL. I run my program and I got the following result:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-17 00:01:26.780 ERROR 20620 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Could anyone help me to resolve that?

PROPERTIES:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store= src/main/resources/bootsecurity.p12
server.ssl.key-password=security
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=bootsecurity
```

MAIN:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("getData")
    public String demo() {
        return "Hello SSL";
    }
}
```

FULL STACK TRACE:

```
2020-06-17 01:35:10.278  INFO 5524 --- [           main] c.example.demo.DemoSslSpringApplication  : Starting DemoSslSpringApplication on LAPTOP-EIJJNNJC with PID 5524 (C:\Users\12345\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.2.RELEASE\DemoSSLSpring\target\classes started by Adrian in C:\Users\12345\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.2.RELEASE\DemoSSLSpring)
2020-06-17 01:35:10.282  INFO 5524 --- [           main] c.example.demo.DemoSslSpringApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-17 01:35:11.537  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2020-06-17 01:35:11.552  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-17 01:35:11.552  INFO 5524 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-06-17 01:35:11.732  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-17 01:35:11.732  INFO 5524 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1382 ms
2020-06-17 01:35:12.013  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-17 01:35:13.125  WARN 5524 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2020-06-17 01:35:13.126  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-17 01:35:13.131  INFO 5524 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-17 01:35:13.156  INFO 5524 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-17 01:35:13.178 ERROR 5524 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoSslSpringApplication.main(DemoSslSpringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1163) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:355) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I tried to fix it but I continue with the same error. I hope someone can help me, I've really been looking to take this away for a little while now. I've done it again in different ways but it's always the same or I present different mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Add `logging.level.<your-package-name>=DEBUG` in your application.properties file

like `logging.level.com.example=DEBUG` -> using this you can enable DEBUGGING in your project

Also, try to change the port of your localhost maybe the port was already assigned

`server.port=8080`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To fix it, In `application.properties` (at src/main/resources) file add the property to change the port number: `server.port=8180`

I hope it can help you too.

Answer (score 1):

In pom file change the scope to runtime from test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, an error in starting the AppContext can have many reasons. Is this the full stacktrace?

Concerning your demo controller, a Slash '/' is missing at the path and the controller has none. Maybe that fixes it, but can't say without full stacktrace.

```
@RestController("/demo") //<like this
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/getData") //<-like this
    public String demo() {
        return "Hello SSL";
    }
}
```

Comment: Now,  I've got the same but with another number error
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-17 01:26:44.819 ERROR 612 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Comment: did you rerun it with logging level debug enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the version . I got solution by this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```